# Insert sequence of values for the same entity

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion, fiware-cygnus

I have Orion working seamlessly, saving entities and retrieving them.

But I'd like to know which is the recommended way to insert (and/or retrieving) a sequence of values for an entity, not updating its value, but **adding** a new value to the entity, so later I can retrieve all values stored for an specific entity ID and "draw" the evolution in a graph.

Updated: I've seen that it may be posible to do it subscribing to a Cosmos instance. Is this the recommended way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommended way for creating historics in FIWARE is through the [Cygnus](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cygnus) tool. It is a connector that, taking advantage of the subscription-notification mechanism, subscribes to an Orion instance in order to be notifed each time certain entities' attributes change.

Cygnus has been designed for persisting the data in several storages: [HDFS](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cygnus/blob/master/doc/design/OrionHDFSSink.md) (Cosmos file system is a HDFS), [MySQL](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cygnus/blob/master/doc/design/OrionMySQLSink.md), [CKAN](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cygnus/blob/master/doc/design/OrionCKANSink.md), [MongoDB](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cygnus/blob/master/doc/design/OrionMongoSink.md), [Kafka](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cygnus/blob/master/doc/design/OrionKafkaSink.md), [STH/Comet](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cygnus/blob/master/doc/design/OrionSTHSink.md)... (and more to come). For each one of them, a particular configurable module (sink, if using the Flume technology jargon) has been created. Just choose the most convenient storage for your application logic.

Comment: Is the Cygnus tool available on the Orion ContextBroker Global Instance?

Comment: I'll recommend you to install it by your own. It is pretty simple as stated here: http://fiware-cygnus.readthedocs.org/en/develop/